# Is this reinterpret_cast undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++

I'm doing the Vulkan tutorial and in one of the lessons they read the shader code into a `std::vector<char>`, but the data has to be passed into a `VkShaderModuleCreateInfo` struct as a `const uint32_t*`. In order to resolve this problem they use `reinterpret_cast`, but I think that this would cause undefined behavior, because the alignment requirement for `uint32_t` is bigger than the alignment requirement for `char`. I would like to know if this is indeed undefined behavior. The code looks like this:

```
std::vector<char> readFile(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ifstream file{filename, std::ios::ate | std::ios::binary};

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error{"failed to open file"};
    }

    std::size_t fileSize{static_cast<size_t>(file.tellg())};
    std::vector<char> buffer(fileSize);
    file.seekg(0);
    file.read(buffer.data(), fileSize);
    file.close();
    return buffer;
}

int main() {
    auto code{readFile("file")};
    auto pCode{reinterpret_cast<const std::uint32_t*>(code.data())};
}
```

If this is undefined behavior, can I resolve the problem in the following way?

```
std::vector<std::uint32_t> readFile(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ifstream file{filename, std::ios::ate | std::ios::binary};

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error{"failed to open file"};
    }

    std::size_t fileSize{static_cast<size_t>(file.tellg())};
    std::vector<std::uint32_t> buffer(fileSize / sizeof(std::uint32_t));
    file.seekg(0);
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), fileSize);
    file.close();
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: warning : fileSize / sizeof(std::uint32_t)
can be truncated : if fileSize is 1 or 2 or 3
what is fileSize / sizeof(std::uint32_t) ?

Comment: @jls28 The shader code uses SPIR-V which is 32-bit word-oriented, but you have a good point. A check wouldn't harm.

Comment: In practice, `std::vector` will use heap memory which is [suitably aligned for any scalar type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc). So alignment should not be a problem. Aliasing might.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code may work in practice, but it does have UB. I wouldn't leave it in such state.

The second snippet looks ok to me, but as already said in the comments, you should check for file size not being a multiple of `sizeof(std::uint32_t)`.

---

Those casts themselves are usually legal. What can be illegal is dereferencing the result.

First, the alignment. The overload of `operator new` that doesn't take the extra alignment parameter aligns to `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` by default, which is enough for all built-in types. From my understanding, this alignment is not guaranteed for the alignment-aware overload, and it's unspecified which overload gets called by [`std::allocator::allocate()`](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.members#lib:allocate,allocator). I'd be surprised if an implementation returned underaligned memory, but it's theoretically possible.

Next, the strict aliasing violation. You're reading `std::uint32_t`s from the array, though nothing wrote them into it before. There are two separate issues:

- Nothing started the lifetime of `std::uint32_t`s in the array (they "don't exist" there). This is unlikely to cause issues in practice, assuming the compiler treats `std::ifstream::read()` as an opaque function (if the function body is unavailable to the compiler, it has to assume it does all the necessary things to make the code legal).
- `std::launder` is missing after the cast. Though I don't think any contemporary compiler enforces this.